# FFMPEG dropping the first two frames of segments generated through seeking

Tags: video, ffmpeg, keyframes

I'm trying to script-cut a 24 fps video and it gets close to the right thing, except for two missing frames at the beginning of every segment I cut with seeking.

I've found out that index-frames (keyframes) could become an issue for seeking, so I first create an intermediate file with every frame as a index frame using this line:

`ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v libx264 -g 1 -c:a copy intermediate.mp4`

Then I proceed to make a cut with this line. Notice I'm drawing some text on top of it:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i intermediate.mp4 -ss 00:00:02.083333333333 -to 00:00:02.875000000000 -vf drawtext=fontfile=DroidSans.ttf:fontsize=48:text="segment2":fontcolor=yellow:box=1:boxborderw=16:boxcolor=black@0.5:x=w/32:y=h/18 output.mp4
```

No matter the length of the segment, the first two frames get dropped.

I'm using python do control ffmpeg.

Any ideas?

---

Edit:

Running ffprobe on one of the generated segments with `ffprobe -hide_banner Nixing_0010_0010.mp4` says the following:

`Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Nixing_0010_0010.mp4':`

`Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.82.101
  Duration: 00:00:02.11, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4717 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 4751 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 2 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : TimeCodeHandler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00`